# Neon 64 bit aarch: compare vector to zero

Tags: assembly, neon, arm64, micro-optimization

I want to compare all the 16 elements of a vector in Neon 64 bit and have a branch if all are equal to zero.

Right now, I have:

```
uaddlv h1, v0.16b
umov w0, v1.s[0]
cmp w0, #0
beq .exit
```

I also tried:

```
uaddlv h1, v0.16b
fcmp s1, #0.0
beq .exit
```

Is this correct? Is there a way to do better? With one single instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
umaxv h1, v0.16b // Get max value across vector
umov w0, v1.s[0] // Move to arm register
cbz w0 .exit // Branch if equal to zero
```

Using intrinsics in C...

```
if(vmaxvq_u16(vector) == 0) { // Is max value zero
    goto exit; // Goto label in C code
}
```

Comment: It's a good answer. In terms of cycles, I think that it's equivalent to my first suggestion (which I eventually implemented). I have also used cbz.